# Function method, finding volume of a sphere

Tags: java

```
public class Part1
{
    public static void main(String args []) 
    { 
        DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        double v;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
        double radius;
        System.out.println( "Enter radius of the basketball: " ); 
        radius = sc.nextDouble(); 
        System.out.println("The volume of the basketball is " +df.format(v));
    }
    public static int volume (int v)
    {   
        v= ( 4.0 / 3.0 ) * Math.PI * Math.pow( radius, 3 ); 
    }
}
```

Basically, i have to let the user input the radius of the basketball and you have to calculate the volume of the basketball. the codes works perfectly, but i don't know how to do it in function method?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "how to do it in procedure method".  If your code works, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Please explain your definition of 'procedure method'?

Comment: public static double volume (double radius)
    {   
     return (4.0/3) * Math.PI * radius * radius * radius;
    }

Comment: @Jason i am sorry i actually meant was function method. Basically function method is a method in which it only returns one value. Therefore, you call the function in the main method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you need to return `double` and pass the `radius` as a double to your `volume` method. You also need to call the function and get the *value*. You should try and restrict the lexical scope of your variables. Something like,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter radius of the basketball: ");
    double radius = sc.nextDouble();
    double v = volume(radius);
    System.out.println("The volume of the basketball is " + df.format(v));
}

public static double volume(double radius) {
    return (4.0 / 3.0) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
}
```

Comment: Also, i meant to say was Function Method, ur code is in function method right? Also can u explain to my why you did this double v = volume(radius);?